# how to find the key with the highest value in a dict of dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have a dict of dicts.

Example:

```
scores[i][subentity_type] = the_score
```

It looks like this:

```
scores = {0:{'SD':1,'ED':2},1:{'SD':0.5,'ED':3}}
```

so i would want a function that returns

```
'SD' --> 0
'ED' --> 1
```

for each `subentity_type`, I want to find the key `i` with the highest score.
do you have an idea if there is a python function to provide this?
thanks!

Comment: could you post your dict of dicts ?  or at least how an inner dict look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `max()` method that accepts an array and determines the max value.

You can turn the values of a dict into a list with `mydict.values()` or as a generator `v for v in mydict.values()`.

You however have a dict of dicts. You can iterate through it with `for dictofdict in mydict.values()`

-> Resulting code:

```
>>> mydict={'a': {'aa': 3, 'ab':7},
...         'b': {'ba': 5, 'bb':9}}
>>> [v for dictofdict in mydict.values() for v in dictofdict.values()]
[3, 7, 5, 9]
>>> max([v for dictofdict in mydict.values() for v in dictofdict.values()])
9
```

A dict of dict where you get the highest value.

Comment: but i want the key i for which the score is highest. i think your code gives the value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't actually explained how your final output should look like but I think you can sort the `dict` items based on values and get the key with highest value. Taking the example for Tin's answer

```
mydict={'a': {'aa': 3, 'ab':7},
        'b': {'ba': 5, 'bb':9}}

new_dict ={}

for k in mydict.keys():
    new_dict[k] = sorted(mydict[k].items(), key= lambda v:-v[1])[0][0]
```

#new_dict = {'a': 'ab', 'b': 'bb'}